# How to make use of a structure pointer inside the structure itself

Tags: c, data-structures

I am studying the following C code:

```
typedef struct msg *m_;
struct msg
{
   long  from;
   long   to;
   m_ link;
};
m_ queue;
```

I would like to see an example that explains the role of the pointer, i.e. `m_`, of the structure inside the structure itself `m_ link`!

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's often used for a linked list with each structure "node" pointing to the next.

Comment: Do **not** `typedef` a pointer! This obfuscates the semantics, makes your code harder to read/maintain.

Comment: @Olaf's advice here is not widely accepted. The majority of C code I've seen and used since 1979 has used typedefs for pointers. Some people adopt the practise of appending `_p` to the name, however. Either way, I agree that `m_` is a bad name.

Comment: @cliffordheath - probably as a result of my late start with C (in 1985) I've never seen a typedef for a pointer. YMMV.

Comment: @cliffordheath: Before you state such, you should check some other questions. If you are up to obfuscating your code and confuse other maintainers, you are welcome. There are even some coding standards which explicitly forbit to typedef pointers, while neforcing `typedef struct`. However, in the 70ies we have entered machine code by hand, short before by punch-cards and many people argued that structured programming was for sissies. Nowadays maintenance/readability has become a major issue for programming. Tempora mutantur.

Comment: One time that pointer typedefs really do help is for defining pointers to functions. The C syntax for these is pretty hard to parse visually!

Comment: @Olaf Note that I wasn't recommending typedefs, just commenting that they are actually quite widely used.

Comment: Typedefs of pointers are common in [Windows data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) , look at the types that start with P (pointer to ... ) or LP (long pointer to) .

Answer (score 0):

To be pedantic: `link` is a pointer. `m_` is not a pointer, it's a typedef. It is used to avoid the need to say "struct msg* link;" inside the struct definition.

As answered in the comment above, the queue is represented by a pointer to the first item, which has a pointer to the second (if any), and so on until you reach a NULL pointer.

It's important to take care when building such lists that no node points to itself or to any precursor, or you get an infinite loop chasing to the tail.

Comment: To be pedantic: `m_` is an alias/synonym for a `struct msg *`, so it is very well a pointer to ... . And you should use markup to format your text.

Comment: Please direct me to the C standard definition for "alias". I think you'll find that `m_` is in fact a typedef, and that alias is not defined in the standard (though "aliasing" is a problem for code optimisers).

Comment: Sorry about the alias; that seems to have slipped into mind from elsewhere, you are right about that, it is not related to `typedef` in the standard itself. It actually is a [_typedef-**name**_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.8) or "synonym" (while one might discuss if "alias" isn't a synonym for "synonym").

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to the structure type inside the structure itself are very often used for linked lists, trees, etc. In your example, it is referring to a queue implementation.

Here is a very minimal example of a stack implementation using a linked list. The functions require the address of a stack pointer, and an empty stack is a NULL pointer.

```
struct linked_stack
{
    int data;
    struct linked_stack *next;
};

void linked_stack_push(linked_stack **stck, int data)
{
    struct linked_stack *node = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_stack));

    if (node != NULL)
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = *stck;
    }

    *stck = node;
}

int linked_stack_top(linked_stack **stck)
{
    if (*stck != NULL)
        return (*stck)->data;
    return 0; /* stack is empty */
}

void linked_stack_pop(linked_stack **stck)
{
    struct linked_stack *node = *stck;

    if (*stck != NULL)
    {
        *stck = node->next;
        free(node);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct linked_stack *stack = NULL;

    linked_stack_push(&stack, 10);
    printf("top of stack = %d\n", linked_stack_top(&stack));
    linked_stack_pop(&stack);

    return 0;
}
```